# How to edit proof environment or minipage

Tags: environments, minipage

Im actually working at my faculty as assistant teacher, and I like to write in latex everything we do in classes, so I use the following format:

```
\fcolorbox{white}{light-gray}{\begin{minipage}{18cm}    
    $ $
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{17.25cm}
            \begin{prob}
            \end{prob}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    $ $
    \end{minipage}}

\fcolorbox{light-gray}{white}{
    \begin{minipage}{18cm}
$ $
        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}{17.25cm}
                \begin{proof}
                \end{proof}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
$ $\end{minipage}}
```

But the problem of minipage is that when the solution is too large, it appears in the next page or it just doesn't appear.

So what I would like to know is to know how to edit the outlines of "proof" environment or to know how to edit `minipage` to it doesn't happen.

Thanks everyone!

ps: as a concrete example you can see [here](https://www.academia.edu/25065571/Ayudant%C3%ADas_de_C%C3%A1lculo_1) the file 
ps: the page's dimensions are

```
\textwidth 18.1cm
\topmargin -2cm
\textheight 25cm
\oddsidemargin -1,2cm
\parindent 0em
\parskip 2ex
```

they are just random for me, I always change it.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `$ $` pairs? Why do you use a `center` environment when a `\centering` directive would generate less vertical whitespace? What are the page dimensions? Which document class do you use?

Comment: Hello @Mico, thanks for commenting. The center environment is to get more simetry. I dont knot the comand \centering (Im googling about it). And the $ $ is because I want to get an space, again just stetic and ignorance about more latex comands. Thanks!

Comment: You need a breakable environment, such as `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`, both provide much more options than `fcolorbox`

Comment: "breakable environment" that is the concept, thank you Christian :)

Comment: @UnPerrito: Yes, `breakable environment` -- unfortunately, there aren't much of them ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example with `tcolorbox`, using breakable boxes for `problem` and `proof` and some customization.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{problembox}[1][]{%
  colframe=white, %% Really?
  colback=lightgray,
  coltitle={black},
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  breakable,
  title={Problem \thetcbcounter},
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  halign=center,
  valign=center,
  #1
 }


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{proofbox}[1][]{%
  colback=white, 
  colframe=lightgray,
  coltitle={black},
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  breakable,
  halign=center,
  valign=center,
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  title={Proof \thetcbcounter},
  #1
}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{problembox}[width=17.25cm]
  \blindtext[2]
\end{problembox}


\begin{proofbox}[width=17.25cm]
  \blindtext[8]
\end{proofbox}


\end{document}
```

Update with a special style for both boxes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% Define a style common to both -- not really necessary, both convenient.     
\tcbset{unperritostyle/.style={%
    coltitle={black},
    enhanced jigsaw,
    sharp corners,
    breakable,
    fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
    halign=center,
    valign=center}
}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{problembox}[1][]{%
  colframe=white, %% Really?
  colback=lightgray,
  unperritostyle,
  title={Problem \thetcbcounter},
  #1
 }


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{proofbox}[1][]{%
  colback=white, 
  colframe=lightgray,
  unperritostyle,
  title={Proof \thetcbcounter},
  #1
}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{problembox}[width=17.25cm]
  \blindtext[2]
\end{problembox}


\begin{proofbox}[width=17.25cm,colback={blue!20!white}]
  \blindtext[8]
\end{proofbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @UnPerrito: topic? I don't understand?

Comment: nevermind, I answered myself. Thanks again dude :)

Comment: @UnPerrito: Ok, happy TeXing

Comment: excuse me, but the box center all the text. Im trying to change it but I don't know how to. What is the "option" related to it?

Comment: @UnPerrito: `halign=center` -- just remove it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40410/discussion-between-unperrito-and-christian-hupfer).